# Pytest conditional statement on same line as assertion not working

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Anyone know why this passes:

```
is_admin = True if app_database.role == 'admin' else False
assert app_request['is_admin'] == is_admin
```

But this fails:

```
assert app_request['is_admin'] is True if app_database.role == 'admin' else False
```

Comment: It looks like your first line has no effect on the `assert` statement in your first example.

Comment: @Selcuk sorry, was a typo. fixed.

Comment: `True if app_database.role == 'admin' else False` is a long way to write `(app_database.role == 'admin')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_admin = True if app_database.role == 'admin' else False` can be written as

```
if app_database.role == 'admin':
    is_admin = True
else:
    is_admin = True
```

so `assert app_request['is_admin'] == is_admin` works.

However, `app_request['is_admin'] is True if app_database.role == 'admin' else False` is actually

```
if app_database.role == 'admin':
    is_admin = app_request['is_admin'] is True
else:
    is_admin = False
```

If `app_database.role` is not `'admin'` **or** `app_request['is_admin']` is `False` than the assertion will actually be

```
assert False
```

which will throw an `AssertionError`

You need to use brackets to define the priority

```
assert app_request['is_admin'] is (True if app_database.role == 'admin' else False)
```

or simpler

```
assert app_request['is_admin'] is (app_database.role == 'admin')
```

which are the equivalent of

```
if app_database.role == 'admin':
    is_admin = True
else:
    is_admin = False

assert app_request['is_admin'] is is_admin
```